# Favicon not showing on google search

Tags: favicon, google-search-console

We have a Quant interview preparation website Puzzledquant.com, and we are not able to see the favicon on google search results. It is visible in the google search console and has size 48x48 pixels and we have gone through the favicon guidelines?

Is there any way we can troubleshoot this or report this to google ?

We have gone through the favicon guidelines and waited 3-4 days for google to crawl the site.